# dependency injection: ctachable error, Argument 1 passed to*

Tags: php

I didn't dependency injection. I read same questions but i can't.

index.php:

```
<?php
    namespace Test;

    use \Test\File\FileControl;
    require "b.php";

    $s = new FileControl;
    $s->taner($re);
```

b.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\File;
require "c.php";

class FileControl {

    public function taner(re $re) {
        $re->taner();
    }
}
```

c.php

```
namespace Test\File;

class re {

    public function taner() {
        echo 'hellow!';
    }
}
```

print: 
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Test\File\FileControl::taner() must be an instance of Test\File\re, null given, called in /index.php on line 9 and defined in /b.php on line 8

what's the wrong, please help

Comment: You stated your problem and provided your code, but you didn't state what your code should produce.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error is pretty specific.. The argument you're passing is invalid, because the method is expecting a certain type of object, and you are passing in the equivalent of `null` instead.

**Edit:** you need to instantiate a `re` object in index.php. So change this...

```
<?php
    namespace Test;

    use \Test\File\FileControl;
    require "b.php";

    $s = new FileControl;
    $s->taner($re);
```

to

```
<?php
namespace Test;

use \Test\File\FileControl;
require "b.php";

$re = new re(); // here's the new line
$s = new FileControl;
$s->taner($re);
```